# Cycles render is making a part grey

Tags: rendering

So when I renderized the image into cycles it got this grey thing that is very annoying

I think the problem is with the particle system

edit: Disabled particles and still there, disabled Subdivision and dissapeared

[image]

Here is before cycles
[image]

Here is after cycles
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer!!

The problem was that the solidify was not enough strong, so the donut part was breaking through. For fixing I increased the thickness

[image]